# Django: Relacionamento de Entidades e Update de Dados

Tags: python, django

Olá, pessoal, tenho um projeto Django que emite relatórios diários das atividades de uma empresa. O projeto é um pouco complexo, mas vou apresentar um exemplo simples de relacionamento que é similar ao problema que tenho.

```
from django.db import models


class Funcionario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    # Fields...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class RelatorioDiario(models.Model):
    # Fields...
    funcionarios = models.ManyToManyField(Funcionario, verbose_name='Funcionários')
    data = models.DateField('Data do Relatório')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Relatório - {self.data}'
```

Tenho uma funcionária chamada "Maria da Silva", que deve constar nos relatórios.

No dia 1, emiti um relatório - uma das funcionárias listadas foi "Maria da Silva".
No dia 2, idem.
...
No dia 9, "Maria da Silva" se casou e passou a adotar seu nome de casada "Maria da Silva Santos".

No dia 10, é feito atualização do cadastro da funcionária. Os próximos relatórios deverá vir com o novo nome. Até aí, tudo bem. O problema é que da forma como o modelo de relacionamento está, essa alteração de nome vai impactar nos relatórios anteriores.

O que eu quero é que, ao atualizar o cadastro da funcionária, os relatórios anteriores continuem com o nome antigo da funcionária, qual seja, "Maria da Silva".

Como implementar isso?

Comment: Já pensou em tratar o nome como se fosse um telefone? no caso, vc usaria uma outra tabela e associaria a esta classe como uma chave estrangeira.